# Unexpected end of JSON input although response was received

Tags: javascript, html, json

I've written this short code to request a json file over REST from a webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button type="submit" onclick="UserAction()">Search</button>

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function UserAction() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("POST", "http://date.jsontest.com/", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  xhttp.send();
  var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
  document.write(response);

  }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

However, in the java script console in chrome I get the following error:

```
VM33:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at UserAction (HTMLPage1.html:17)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (HTMLPage1.html:9)
```

But when I check the network response in the console, I can see the response in the following format which is correct, but it's also not displayed on the webpage:

```
{
   "time": "02:08:35 PM",
   "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1508767715990,
   "date": "10-23-2017"
}
```

I have no idea what could cause this problem, does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Also `document.write` is probably for debugging, but you should just use console.log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xhttp.send();` is asynchronous. This means that when you do `JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);` there is nothing in the response yet. You must use the event...

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        document.write(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

first Convert the JavaScript object into a string with JSON.stringify().
then use JSON.parse

```js
var responseText = {
  "time": "02:08:35 PM",
  "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1508767715990,
  "date": "10-23-2017"
};
var response = JSON.stringify(responseText);
var result = JSON.parse(response);;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why would you do this?  There is no value in converting an object into a JSON string and back again in this case...

Comment: This has absolutely no value... You completely removed the AJAX call while it was the only failure point...